# Accessing data from subscribe

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am learning Angular 2 and have subscribed to my service and have returned the data, however I now need to `for()` loop over it before it gets to the view, so I have pushed my `json` into an array which is already an array but not sure if this is correct.

Basically I want to pass my subscribed data to a method on my controller

```
public sublocation = [];
  private subscriptions = [];
  constructor(private statusService : StatusService) { 

  }  

  public getAllStatusList(){
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.statusService.getStatusAPI()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.sublocation.push(data);
        },
        error => console.log('Server Error'), 
      )
    );
  }

public getSublocation(){
    console.log(this.sublocation);
    //TRYING TO DO STUFF HERE like if sublocation == london
}
```

**json Sample**

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "19",
      "parentTag": "0",
      "name": "London",
      "deliveryType": "E",
      "enabled": "T",
      "outageTag": [],
      "sub": [
        {
          "id": "25",
          "parentTag": "19",
          "name": "London::Gatwick",
          "deliveryType": "E",
          "enabled": "T",
          "outageTag": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

**Service**

```
 export class StatusService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { 

  }

  public getStatusAPI(): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get(environment.api)
      .map((response: Response) => this.getStatusList(response))
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
  }

  public getStatusList(responseData:any){
    let data = [];
    let res = responseData.json();
    for(let prop in res) {
      data.push(res[prop])
    }
    //console.log(data);
    return data;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is invalid json, and array [] needs to have objects {}, you have array inside array, then {}

Comment: Please share how the service returns the data exactly and what you need to do with it exactly

Comment: @SumamaWaheed Arrays don't need to have objects. And arrays can be nested. `[[2]]` is valid JSON

Comment: @ottz0, can you just post exactly how does your json look like when it arrives, before any loops etc? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the data you have presented in your question as JSON (which would not be JSON anymore), is the data you end up with, after looping and pushing it to arrays. So the original (and actual) JSON probably looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "parentTag": "0",
    "name": "London",
    "deliveryType": "E",
    "enabled": "T",
    "outageTag": [],
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "25",
        "parentTag": "19",
        "name": "London::Gatwick",
        "deliveryType": "E",
        "enabled": "T",
        "outageTag": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

That means that your looping and pushing to a new array is unnecessary, you can just do this:

```
return this.http.get(environment.api)
  .map(res => res.json())
```

And in your component subscribe to the data and do whatever you like. You mentioned in your question that you wanted to loop through the array and checking the location. So do something like this:

```
this.statusService.getStatusAPI()
  .subscribe(d => {
    this.data = d;
    this.loopData();
  })

loopData() {
  // loop through array
  this.data.forEach(x => {
    // check name property of object
    if(x.name == 'London') {
      alert('An Object with name London found!');
    }
  });
}
```

With this solution you can now easily access the data in your Array of objects, like above, looping through the array and then refer to object properties like `x.name`, `x.parentTag` etc...